# How to output all sequences with bwa mem, not `*`?

Tags: sequence-alignment, bwa

I've been running `bwa mem -a` for alignment, using the `-a` flag---this will

> output all alignments for SE or unpaired PE

I've noticed in the SAM that there are several alignments with `*` in the `SEQ` and `QUAL` fields. Based on the documentation:

> 10. SEQ: segment SEQuence. This field can be a ‘*’ when the sequence is not stored. If not a ‘*’, the length of the sequence must equal the
>       sum of lengths of M/I/S/=/X operations in CIGAR. An ‘=’ denotes the
>       base is identical to the reference base. No assumptions can be made on
>       the letter cases.
> 11. QUAL: ASCII of base QUALity plus 33 (same as the quality string in the Sanger FASTQ format). A base quality is the phred-scaled base
>       error probability which equals −10 log10 Pr{base is wrong}. This field
>       can be a ‘*’ when quality is not stored. If not a ‘*’, SEQ must not be
>       a ‘*’ and the length of the quality string ought to equal the length
>       of SEQ.

it appears the sequence isn't stored.

I would strongly prefer to have the sequence in this case. Is there any to direct bwa to output these sequences?

Comment: Are you aware that many of these records are secondary/supplementary alignments? Does your workfow/model require/benefit from these alignments and handle them correctly?

Comment: @DanielStandage "Are you aware that many of these records are secondary/supplementary alignments?" Yes. " Does your workfow/model require/benefit from these alignments and handle them correctly?". Benefit, yes.

Answer (score 5):

I don't believe that is an option.  Internally we created a [patch](https://github.com/lh3/bwa/pull/36) and submitted it to [BWA](https://github.com/lh3/bwa) however that was 4 years ago and it has not been accepted.

Comment: Thanks. Did @user172818 ever give a reason why this feature isn't included?

Comment: see also https://www.biostars.org/p/352930/

Comment: @Pierre This is a great tool Pierre! I think it runs successfully for me. The problem is, I get errors downstream when using `samtools view`, i.e.. `[E::sam_parse1] CIGAR and query sequence are of different length` Are there work arounds?

Comment: I didn't test it with all the possible cases. Can you please try to isolate a minimal sam file containing the faulty reads ( all the reads with the same name) and send a bug report ? https://github.com/lindenb/jvarkit/issues/

Comment: @Pierre I may send you an e-mail instead. Thanks Pierre!

Comment: plindenbaum reverse(oohay) fr but I'll need a minimal failing SAM file.